# Algorithm negotiation fail deploying iOS app in OSX "El Capitan"

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I'm trying to deploy an app to a macbook with "El Capitan" OS Version but the MacTransfer.exe of Genexus says "Algorithm negotiation fail". I have already enable the remote login and also made the change in de etc/ssh/sshd_config for PasswordAuthentication yes.

Also if I try to connect with open ssh from my windows laptop I'm able to do it.

is there another line to be included in the ssh?

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been fixed recently.

You may patch your GX installation by replacing the files contained in the following zip files:

- [GeneXus Salto](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14729664/iOS.zip)
- [GeneXus Evolution 3](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40920867/MacTransferXev3.zip)

Within : %GeneXusInstallation%/iOS