# JSch algorithm negotiation fail with OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, algorithm, ssh, ant

We have a build script that uses the Ant `<scp>` task to upload files to a Mac server.  This has been working fine for a year or more with the server running OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion), but we recently upgraded it to OSX 10.11 (El Capitan) and now the `<scp>` task fails with this exception:

`com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail`

Switching on verbose mode, the log looks like this:

```
[scp] Connecting to **SERVER-ADDRESS**:2220
[scp] Connecting to **SERVER-ADDRESS** port 2220
[scp] Connection established
[scp] Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
[scp] Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.51
[scp] CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
[scp] CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
[scp] diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 is not available.
[scp] SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
[scp] SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
[scp] kex: server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
[scp] kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
[scp] kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
[scp] kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
[scp] kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
[scp] kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
[scp] kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
[scp] kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
[scp] kex: server:
[scp] kex: server:
[scp] kex: client: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
[scp] kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
[scp] kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
[scp] kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
[scp] kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
[scp] kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
[scp] kex: client: none
[scp] kex: client: none
[scp] kex: client:
[scp] kex: client:
[scp] Disconnecting from **SERVER-ADDRESS** port 2220
```

So the problem is that a single algorithm is not supported by both client and server, as discussed in this similar SO post: [JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263630/jschexception-algorithm-negotiation-fail) and various other places.  However, from the logs it looks to me like the client and server **do** both support at least one algorithm, namely "aes128-ctr":

```
[scp] kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
```

and

```
[scp] kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
```

So I don't understand why they can't negotiate an algorithm, but even so I went ahead and installed the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files, as suggested in that other SO question - you can see in the above line that the client supports 256-bit algorithms now.  That doesn't make a difference, presumably because the server supports "aes256-ctr" and the client supports "aes256-cbc".  But I still don't understand why it can't use "aes128-ctr"

Note, the client machine is running Windows, so based on something I read elsewhere (can't remember exactly where), I have also tried clearing Putty's cache of SSH keys - that also made no difference (not that I was expecting it to - I'm just trying stuff now...)

Frustratingly, it looks like this SO post - [Algorithm negotiation fail deploying iOS app in OSX "El Capitan"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102849/algorithm-negotiation-fail-deploying-ios-app-in-osx-el-capitan) - deals with the same issue, and there was a resolution, but the answerer just says that the problem is fixed in his product without explaining what the fix was, and I don't have enough reputation to post a comment asking for more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorithm negotiation is not only about cipher, but also Key exchange and MACs. You don't have any common key exchange algorithm:

```
[scp] kex: server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
[scp] kex: client: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

The client set is really small. You will probably have to allow additional Kex method on client side.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and informative reply!  For anyone reading this in the future, it turned out that upgrading to JSch 0.1.53 fixed this, because it supports more kex methods

Comment: I wanted to propose the update, but saw you have 0.1.52 so I thought there will not be a bug difference. Next time smarter. Glad to help.